# how to make a stroke rounded

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I'm creating a progress circle but I want the edge of the progress circle line to be rounded, [this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY17B.png) and [this is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzGkA.png).

here is my code

```
  const strokeWidth = 2;
  const center = size / 2;
  const radius = size / 2 - strokeWidth / 2;

       <Circle
          ref={progressRef}
          stroke="#FFF"
          cx={center}
          cy={center}
          r={radius}
          strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
          strokeDasharray={circumference}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strokeLinecap prop on the Path to round:

```
<Path
  stroke="black"
  fill="none"
  strokeLinecap="round"
  strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
  strokeDasharray={circumference}
/>
```

Found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60725607/rounded-corners-for-arc-progress-in-react-native-svg)